# How to print QCC_Log messages when running gtest in alljoyn

Tags: googletest, scons, alljoyn

Alljoyn code has a number of logging functions, what is the command line environment variable that needs to be added to get them to print when running gtest.  The scons command I am running is:

```
scons OS=darwin CPU=x86 BR=on BINDINGS=cpp SERVICES="about,config,notification,controlpanel" BUILD_SERVICES_SAMPLES=on SDKROOT=$PWD GTEST_DIR=‘/Users/Finch/GTEST/googletest'
```

Comment: You'll likely need to look at the way Alljoyn has used SCons and how to get the variable you want propagated to the Environment() which is being used to run gtest.

Answer (score 0):

The environmental variable you need to set is ER_DEBUG_ALL.

```
export ER_DEBUG_ALL=1
```

You can get different levels of debugging from 1 to 7.